# Issue with React useEffect not resetting in Capacitor Camera Component

Tags: capacitor-plugin

I'm facing an issue with the `useEffect` hook in my React component that utilizes the **Capacitor** **Camera** plugin. The problem occurs when there are errors in my code, specifically when dealing with wrong image selection or closing the camera. It seems like the `useEffect` hook does not reset properly, preventing me from remounting the component when errors are present. Everything works as expected when there are no errors.

Here is my component.

```
interface TakePhotoProps {
  onCaptureImage: (capturedImage: File) => void;
}

const TakePhoto: FC<TakePhotoProps> = ({ onCaptureImage }) => {
  const [, setCapturedImage] = useState<File | undefined>();

  var flag = false;
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const { Toast } = useToast();

  const openCamera = async () => {
    try {
      defineCustomElements(window);
      const capturedPhoto = await Camera.getPhoto({
        quality: 90,
        resultType: CameraResultType.DataUrl,
        source: CameraSource.Camera,
        width: 620,
        height: 480,
      });

      if (capturedPhoto && capturedPhoto.dataUrl) {
        const blob = await fetch(capturedPhoto.dataUrl).then((res) => res.blob());
        const isValidFileType = /^image\/(jpeg|jpg|png|gif)$/.test(blob.type);
        if (isValidFileType) {
          const imageFile = new File([blob], 'image.jpg', { type: 'image/jpeg' });

          let fileToScan: File = imageFile;
          setCapturedImage(fileToScan);
          onCaptureImage(fileToScan);
        } else {
          Toast.error(t('error-select-image'));
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {}
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(flag);
    if (!flag) {
      openCamera();
      flag = true;
    }
  }, [flag]);

  return <></>;
};

export default TakePhoto;
```